# How can I send a text file to GAS , using cURL?

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send the content of the text file to Google Spread Sheet, using cURL.

test.txt

```
this is the message from local
```

on the local shell

```
 curl -F name=value -F data1=@test.txt "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec"
```

in the Google Apps Script in Google Spread Sheet

```
function doPost(e){
   Logger.log(e);
}
```

then the log is

```
 Fri Jul 12 08:34:28 PDT 2013 INFO: {queryString=null, parameter={name=value}, contextPath=, parameters={name=[value]}, contentLength=316}
```

I can not find the parameter "data1" that I sent.

So how can I recieve the content of the file I sent??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to POST data using [--data-url-encode](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) instead of [-F](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F)

Command

```
 curl --data-urlencode name=value --data-urlencode data2@test.txt "https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/exec" -L --insecure
```

Output

```
 {"queryString":null,"postData":{"contents":"name=value&data1=This%20is%20the%20content%20of%20my%20test.txt%20file","type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","name":"postData","length":70},"parameter":{"data1":"This is the content of my test.txt file","name":"value"},"contextPath":"","parameters":{"data1":["This is the content of my test.txt file"],"name":["value"]},"contentLength":70}
```

Apps Script

```
 function doPost(e) {

    var xx = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
   return xx;
}
```